# How I do to fixed height px at navigation menu bar and align elements

Tags: html, css

I would like to adjust the height of navigation menu bar to 37px(height of logo) a part of this I would like to adjust icons with its text and adjust the dropdown menu also to navigation bar and your content align icon-text.

Sorry but the css styles for my is dificult, I'm beginner.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropdownClick() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Definimos la fuente personalizada para la web */

@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham-Light;
  src: url('../../assets/webfonts/Gotham-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham-Medium;
  src: url('../../assets/webfonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
html {
  font-family: Gotham-Light;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.optionMenu {
  font-family: Gotham-Medium;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
/* Def. Navigation Bar */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dedee1;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn,
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e0f2fd;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.iconimg {
  float: left;
}
.icontxt {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.dropbtn i {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="assets/images/brand-logo.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="optionMenu">
      <a href="#page1.html"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 30px">work</i> Page1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="optionMenu ">
      <a href="#page2.html"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 30px ">photo</i> Page2</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right " class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn " onclick="dropdownClick()"><i class="material-icons " style="font-size: 30px ">face</i> Username</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#settings.html"><i class="material-icons">settings</i> settings</a>
        <a href="#change_pass.html "><i class="material-icons">lock</i>  change password</a>
        <a href="#logout.html"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:18px">power_settings_new</i> log out</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I've tried a very lot of variants but I do not find the solution.

Comment: What "variants" have you tried to achieve your desired look?

Comment: Please add jsfiddle for your code

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik I believe it's generally considered a better practice on SO to use their snippet feature rather than JS Fiddle if possible. Fiddles can expire leaving future viewers to guess at what the question's content was. Overall the content absolutely should have arranged into logical sections, which it now is.

Comment: 1) I have tried to define a container style and create the options menu: 'image + text' to use display: flex and define boxes to each elements with fixed width.

Comment: Ok @MattD sorry I'm a beginner here. I'm going to do it.

Comment: 2) Another variant, I have tried to assign an absolute value to navigation bar and your components using % values.

Comment: 3) Last variant I attached code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this,

edited CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham-Light;
  src: url('../../assets/webfonts/Gotham-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Gotham-Medium;
  src: url('../../assets/webfonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
html {
  font-family: Gotham-Light;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.optionMenu {
  font-family: Gotham-Medium;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
/* Def. Navigation Bar */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */    /* removed */
  background-color: #dedee1;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn,
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 16px 3px 16px; /* edited */
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* edited */
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e0f2fd;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 178px;  /* edited */
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; /* edited */
}
.iconimg {
  float: left;
}
.icontxt {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.dropbtn i {
  /* float: left; */ /* removed */
}

/* Added new css style */
.material-icons{   
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

And edited HTML code snippet -

```
<img height="37px" src="assets/images/brand-logo.png" />
```

Comment: Good! Only a thing, the background color of the navigation bar is write and I can not change it!

Comment: If it removed: overflow: hidden;  then the background is without color. I'm try other options of overflow.

Comment: Already it's working fine. Thanks for your help. The problem was the background color apply in the nav not in the ul. The overflow removed too.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the following change should give you what you want:

Remove the padding here ( the padding on your a tags are causing your nav bar to appear larger)

```
li a,
.dropbtn,
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 14px 16px; */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Add the following class style:

```
.material-icons { 
  vertical-align: middle;
```

}

This will make your text and icons line up.

I think this covers what you want?

Comment: More or less, the 'boxes' of text is more less than logo and the effect is wrong, not fit to navigation menu. Also at bottom of logo there is an grey line of the navigation bar, it's not fit too.

Comment: Your image does not load for us, so it is difficult to properly check for the cause... Can you maybe give a mockup image of the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I do not know to insert image into the message :(